# If $(3+\sqrt{8})^{2023} = a + b\sqrt{8}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers, then $a$ is the product of two numbers which differ by 2.

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, integer-sequences

For clarity, I'm using the short-hand $\alpha = 3 + \sqrt{8}$ and $\beta = 3 - \sqrt{8}$.

$\boxed{\alpha + \beta = 6\text{ and }\alpha \beta = 1}$.

$\text{Define } (b_n)_{n \geq 1} := \frac{\alpha^{2n-1}+\beta^{2n-1}}{2}$ (this will always give us the rational part of the number $(3+\sqrt{8})^{2n-1}$).

$b_1 = 3 \text{; } b_2 = 99 \text{; } b_3 = 3363$; ...

My task is then equivalent to showing $b_{1012} = m(m+2)$ for some natural $m$, or, equivalently, to show that $b_{1012} + 1$ is a perfect square.

What I've managed to show/notice:

- $b_1 = 1 \cdot 3$, $b_2 = 9 \cdot 11$, $b_3 = 57 \cdot 59$, ... hence I conjecture they all satisfy the condition I'm asked to prove for $b_{1012}$.
- $b_{n+1} = 34b_{n} - b_{n-1} \text{, } \forall n \geq 2$;
- $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}} = 17 + 6\sqrt{8} = \alpha^2$;
- $\forall n \geq 1 \text{, } b_{n} = (A)b_{2} + (B)b_1$ for whole $A$ and $B$.
- A cool fact that pops out from my calculations: $17 + 6\sqrt{8} \approx 34-\frac{1}{34}$.

I would love some further insight into this problem and/or a full solution will also be appreciated.

Source: Moldavian Math Republican Olympiad Grade 12.

Comment: Use $a^2-8b^2=1$ if possible.

Comment: already did, did not seem to find anything satisfactory.

Comment: Quick computations show that this claim appears to be true for any odd exponent.  That might be easier to prove.  But...please edit to provide the source for the problem.  Contests frequently feature the current year.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\alpha =3+2\sqrt2=(\sqrt2+1)^2=\gamma^2$
$\beta =3-2\sqrt2=(\sqrt2-1)^2=\delta^2$
$$b_n+1 = \frac{\alpha^{2n-1}+\beta^{2n-1}+2}{2} = \left(\frac{\gamma^{2n-1}+\delta^{2n-1}}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2 $$
because $2n-1$ is odd, the value inside the parentheses is whole.

Comment: i hate that i didn't notice it. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Although a bit more involved, here is a solution using linear recurrence relations.

---

**Deriving Recurrences for $\pmb{a_n}$ and $\pmb{b_n}$**

Define $a_n,b_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ as $a_n+b_n\sqrt8=\left(3+\sqrt8\right)^n$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
a_n+b_n\sqrt8
&=\left(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}\sqrt8\right)\left(3+\sqrt8\right)\tag{1a}\\
&=(3a_{n-1}+8b_{n-1})+(a_{n-1}+3b_{n-1})\sqrt8\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
Equating the coefficients of $1$ and $\sqrt8$ in $(1)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
a_n&=3a_{n-1}+8b_{n-1}\tag{2a}\\
b_n&=\phantom{3}a_{n-1}+3b_{n-1}\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
a_n&=3a_{n-1}+8a_{n-2}+24b_{n-2}\tag{3a}\\
&=6a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a):}$ substitute $n\mapsto n-1$ in $\text{(2b)}$ to get $b_{n-1}=a_{n-2}+3b_{n-2}$
$\phantom{\text{(3a):}}$ then use for $b_{n-1}$ in $\text{(2a)}$
$\text{(3b):}$ substitute $n\mapsto n-1$ in $\text{(2a)}$ to get $8b_{n-2}=a_{n-1}-3a_{n-2}$
$\phantom{\text{(3b):}}$ then mulitiply by $3$ to get $24b_{n-2}=3a_{n-1}-9a_{n-2}$
$\phantom{\text{(3b):}}$ then use for $24b_{n-2}$ in $\text{(3a)}$

Since $\text{(2a)}$ says $b_n=\frac{a_{n+1}-3a_n}8$, we see that $b_n$ also satisfies the recurrence in $(3)$: $b_n=6b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}$.

---

**An Observation**

Since $a_0=1$ and $a_1=3$ and $a_n$ satisfies the recursion in $(3)$, we get the first several terms
$$
1,3,17,99,577,3363,\dots\tag4
$$
a bit of observation shows that this sequence is
$$
0^2+1,2^2-1,4^2+1,10^2-1,24^2+1,58^2-1,\dots\tag5
$$
The terms which are squared appear to follow the recursion $c_n=2c_{n-1}+c_{n-2}$.

---

**Proving the Observation**

Suppose that $c_n=2c_{n-1}+c_{n-2}$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
c_n^2
&=(2c_{n-1}+c_{n-2})^2\tag{6a}\\
&=4c_{n-1}^2+c_{n-2}^2+4c_{n-1}c_{n-2}\tag{6b}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
c_nc_{n-1}
&=(2c_{n-1}+c_{n-2})c_{n-1}\tag{7a}\\
&=2c_{n-1}^2+c_{n-1}c_{n-2}\tag{7b}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
c_n^2-4c_{n-1}^2-c_{n-2}^2&=4c_{n-1}c_{n-2}\tag{8a}\\
c_{n-1}^2-4c_{n-2}^2-c_{n-3}^2&=4c_{n-2}c_{n-3}\tag{8b}\\
c_n^2-5c_{n-1}^2+3c_{n-2}^2+c_{n-3}^2&=8c_{n-2}^2\tag{8c}\\
c_n^2-5c_{n-1}^2-5c_{n-2}^2+c_{n-3}^2&=0\tag{8d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(8a):}$ apply $(6)$
$\text{(8b):}$ apply $(6)$
$\text{(8c):}$ subtract $\text{(8b)}$ from $\text{(8a)}$ and apply $(7)$
$\text{(8d):}$ cancel

Thus, $c_n^2$ satisfies the linear recurrence in $\text{(8d)}$. The characteristic polynomial of the linear recurrence in $\text{(8d)}$ can be factored as
$$
x^3-5x^2-5x+1=\underbrace{\ (x+1)\ \vphantom{\left(x^2\right)}}_{(-1)^n}\underbrace{\left(x^2-6x+1\right)}_{a_n,b_n}\tag9
$$
That is, if $c_n=2c_{n-1}+c_{n-2}$, then $c_n^2$ is a linear combination of $a_n$, $b_n$, and $(-1)^n$.

Suppose that $c_0=0$, $c_1=2$, and $c_2=4$. Then, solving for the coefficients of $a_n$, $b_n$, and $(-1)^n$, we get
$$
c_n^2=a_n-(-1)^n\tag{10}
$$
Thus, we have shown that our observation in $(5)$ is true:
$$
a_n=c_n^2+(-1)^n\tag{11}
$$
where $c_0=0$, $c_1=2$, and $c_n=2c_{n-1}+c_{n-2}$.

---

**Answering the Question**

Looking at the odd indexed terms, we get
$$
\begin{align}
a_{2n+1}
&=c_{2n+1}^2-1\tag{12a}\\
&=(c_{2n+1}-1)(c_{2n+1}+1)\tag{12b}
\end{align}
$$
as proposed in the question.

Comment: thank you for this solution!